# How to get into second vertex color?

Tags: import, vertex-colors

Edit: For all viewers which can have similar problem - if your addon is importing vertex color but you don't see second or another one then you should make sure that this script even has these kind of feature.

I am working on *.dff files imported from game to blender so I can modify it and export back. Everything is working perfectly except I did not think about night in the game. Default files from game have both, night and day vertex color (in one file as one object) but I can display only day vertex color as default in Blender. I mean, I did not see any way to get to into second one. Menu -> Data -> Vertex Color -> shows one col. Is there a way or it depends on export/import .dff script?

Comment: Blender supports multiple vertex colors on a mesh, but the add-on you're using doesn't seem to import more than one.

Comment: It seems to me like you said but there's a lot of python code inside that should import everyting. There it is - https://pastebin.com/nEsSJj4v

Comment: Just from a brief glance at the code it doesn't seem to import more than one set of RGB vertex colors.

Comment: I will try to fix it now by get some knowledge about python. Thank you for directions, appreciate it.